# Compiled with problems Xiaomi Browser on android

Tags: reactjs, browser, compiler-errors, runtime-error, compatibility

I uploaded my project to the ubuntu server. The project is written in NodeJS and React, axios, mobx were additionally used. The version of React used is already outdated 17.0.1, Node 16.15.1. In general, in all modern and relevant browsers such as Chrome, Safari, Mozilla, Opera, etc. My site works without problems, but MI Browser users are getting a compilation error.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.29.3",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "mobx": "^6.6.1",
    "mobx-react-lite": "^3.4.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.7.2",
    "react-datepicker": "^4.11.0",
    "react-dates": "^21.8.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-intersection-observer": "^9.4.3",
    "react-phone-input-2": "^2.15.1",
    "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.2.23",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-scroll-parallax": "^3.4.2",
    "react-scrollmagic": "^2.3.0",
    "react-slick": "^0.29.0",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.4.5",
    "react-visibility-sensor": "^5.1.1",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

app.js:

```
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import AppRouter from "./components/AppRouter";
import NavBar from "./components/NavBar";
import { observer } from "mobx-react-lite";
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Context } from "./index";
import { check } from "./http/userAPI";
import { Spinner } from "react-bootstrap";
import "./App.css";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import ScrollToTopButton from "./components/ArrowUp";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import Main from "./pages/Main";


function ScrollToTop() {
    const { pathname } = useLocation();

    useEffect(() => {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }, [pathname]);

    return null;
}

const App = observer(() => {
    const { user } = useContext(Context);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        document.querySelector("body").style.opacity = "1";
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        check()
            .then((data) => {
                user.setUser(data);
                user.setIsAuth(true);
            })
            .finally(() => setLoading(false));
    },[]);

    if (loading) {
        return <Spinner animation="grow" variant="info" className="spin" />;
    }

    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <ScrollToTop />
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact component={Main} />
                <Route>
                    <Header />
                    <NavBar />
                    <AppRouter />
                    <ScrollToTopButton />
                    <Footer />
                </Route>
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
});

export default App;
```

index.js

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import React, {createContext} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import UserStore from "./store/UserStore";
import CarStore from "./store/CarStore"
import TruckStore from "./store/TruckStore";


export const Context = createContext(null)


ReactDOM.render(

    <Context.Provider value={{
        user: new UserStore(),
        car: new CarStore(),
        truck: new TruckStore()
    }}>
        <App />
    </Context.Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I've tried changing package versions, separating code logic, and nothing worked, it still appears [Compiled with problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1sHp.jpg). I even thought it might be a matter of the brandmauer, I added ports there, but it is obvious that the error is caused by React, but I don’t know where specifically. Perhaps you have encountered such a problem, I am also more perplexed by the fact that the last project was made by the same stack, but it works fine in Mi Browser.
[98657:58 bundle.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FspIA.png)